# How to access value_counts() data in pandas?

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

When I do a count of values in a Panda, who do I access a column name?

Consider the US Census dataset. I can count the number of counties in each state with:

```
df2["STNAME"].value_counts()
```

Which returns a series which looks like this:

```
Alabama    24
Alaska     23
Arizona     1
etc ...
Name: STNAME, dtype: int64
```

How do I access the State name (the STNAME, which actually I'm not sure is the index, since in SQL terms this is, I think, just a view on the data).

Comment: I can tell you it is indeed the index, so use `df2["STNAME"].value_counts().index` if you want an index object, or `df2["STNAME"].value_counts().index.tolist()` if you want a list. If you only want unique counts, I think `df2["STNAME"].unique()` is a better option.

Comment: So if I do `df2["STNAME"].value_counts().index` I get the index, but if I want the highest value, and do: 
`df2["STNAME"].value_counts().max().index` I get a syntax error. Why?

Comment: @Dirk: `max` of series return an integer. So, there is no `index` on it

Comment: @AndyL. so how do I get the max (not the max count, but the state associated with the max?

Comment: sorry, typo, i meant `.idxmax()`

Comment: = `df2["STNAME"].value_counts().idxmax()`